# find HtmlInputCheckbox control in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem contact in rptList.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox cBox = contact.FindControl("chkteklif") as HtmlInputCheckBox;
        if (contact is HtmlInputCheckBox)
        {
            string a = cBox.Value;
        }
    }

}
```

i used this code but this code couldn't find HtmlInputCheckBox..  any idea ?

Comment: what error are you getting?show the Repeater's Designer code...

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Instead of `contact is HtmlInputCheckBox` you might want to use `cBox is HtmlInputCheckBox` since `contact` is the `RepeaterItem`. But that would also be redundant since you've already casted it to that type. So you should check for `null` instead.

Comment: What is "chkteklif"? Is it the id?

Comment: please post your html markup to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You should show us the aspx markup of the `Repeater`. But i assume that you've forgotten to add `runat="server"`.

Apart from that, you have a typo in your code. Instead of `contact is HtmlInputCheckBox` you might want to use `cBox is HtmlInputCheckBox` since `contact` is the `RepeaterItem`. But that would also be redundant since you've already casted it to that type. So you should check for `null` instead.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem contact in rptList.Items)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox cBox = contact.FindControl("chkteklif") as HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (cBox != null)
    {
        string a = cBox.Value;
    }
}
```

How your `html-checkbox` should look like:

```
<input id="chkteklif" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="check me" />
```

or (from your comment), try this:

```
<input id="chkteklif" type="checkbox" onclick='<%# "rptlist_onchange(this," + Eval("userid") + " );" %>' value="ilan" />
```

Comment: @Tim sorry, I edited your answer, I think I misunderstood. Can you please reread your answer? thanks.

Comment: Is `chkteklif` the correc Id of it? Have you used the debugger(with a breakpoint on the `null`-check) to see if it is only null or the wrong type?

Comment: yes chkteklif is the correct Id. i used debugger too and i only see null value.

Comment: also if i add the runat server in html input it gives an error. Error is " the form is not well formed "

Comment: @dpp: Yes, you misunderstood. The `is` checks the type, your edit(`cBox in HtmlInputCheckBox`) is pointless ;)

Comment: @dangerous35: Then you should show what you've tried since it is no problem to add `runat="server"` to any html control. Edited my answer to show an example.

Comment: @Tim : <input id="chkteklif" type="checkbox" onclick="rptlist_onchange(this,<%#Eval("ilanId") %>);" value="ilan"  />
this is the my input in repeater

Comment: @dangerous35: Edited my answer again to show you how to format the checkbox correctly (hopefully).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought so. Now I learned a new keyword "is", thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not overwriting your controls on Page_Load.  you will need to check if its a post back.

Comment: i checked. i m sure. All times cbox comes null.

Comment: like others have said, we are going to need more info like your markup and page_load

Answer (score 0):

try

```
HtmlInputCheckBox cbox = (HtmlInputCheckBox)sender;
```